# Swift 2 : How to downcast an Array of Objects

Tags: swift, mapping, alamofire

I have this Array and I am trying to POST it to backend, but got really confused with all the casting

```
valuesDictionary=["medication": Optional("Novocain"), "dateOfBirth": Optional(2001-    01-01 00:00:00 +0000), "lastName": Optional("Berthold"), "allergies":     Optional("Heuschnupfen"), "firstName": Optional("Alexander"), "Blutgruppe": Optional("A"), "PostalAddress": Optional(Eureka.PostalAddress(street: Optional("Gleimstraße"), state: nil, postalCode: Optional("10123"), city: Optional("Berlin"), country: Optional("DE")))]
```

trying to feed it into:

```
let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, Config.profileUpdate, parameters: valuesDictionary , encoding: .JSON)
```

I tried different things like:

```
let valuesDictionary = form.values() as! [String:AnyObject]
```

to downcast into the expected form but it just showing:

```
fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes
```

Comment: Could you please post some of the error and where you are getting them?

Comment: if I try to downcast like this:
let valuesDictionary = form.values() as! [String:AnyObject]
I get:
fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

Comment: how is your valuesDictionary declared? How is forms declared?

Comment: form.values() is the method to get all values from the eureka library form.

Comment: Try [String: Any?]

Comment: it is already of type [String:Any?]...forced cast to same type has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optionals aren't `AnyObject`s because `Optional` is an `enum` (a value type). You'll need to unwrap your optionals before you shove them in your dictionary.

Comment: i tried like this:
let valuesDictionary = form.values()
if let unwrapped = valuesDictionary {
    print(unwrapped)
}
just getting: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any?]'

Comment: this works for single wrapped values, there is no chance to get rid of all optionals in the array at once?

Comment: Map wouldve been the right thing to use here, but unfortunately, calling map on a dictionary returns an array of (key, value) tuples, not an actual dictionary. You can manually make a new duct in a for loop, by unwrapping all the values of your existing dict

Comment: meh this is what I ended up doing

Comment: @goran Has your question been satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

I had some crazy stuff happening with the values I wanted to throw into Firebase. I ended up finding where they originally got away from their expectations and fixed that.

Wherever you've declared something that is different than what you want the final result to be, make it what the final result should be. In this case, wherever it's declared as anything other than an object, make it an object.

It's more work but it would save you some time in the end.